# webpack custom loader just choose one file instead all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, webpack, webpack-4

I expected my custom loader to apply to all js files in a folder, but just choose one.

## Loader

```
function loader(content) {
  //some logic to modify
  return content
}
```

## Webpack config #1

```
{
   test: /\.js$/,
   loader: "./src/org/loader/my-loader.js",
   include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
   exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

## Webpack config #2

```
{
   test: /\.*$/,
   loader: "./src/org/loader/my-loader.js",
   exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

## folder and files

```
./postcss.config.js
./README.md
./.gitignore
./.babelrc
./package.json
./src
./src/images
./src/images/logo-up.jpg
./src/index.js
./src/pages
./src/pages/map
./src/pages/map/index.js
./src/pages/map/index.html
./src/pages/home
./src/pages/home/index.js
./src/pages/home/index.html
./src/fonts
./src/fonts/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf
./src/index.html
./src/org/loader/my-loader.js
./src/route/nourl
./src/route/nourl/index.js
./src/styles
./src/styles/index.scss
./src/styles/_variables.scss
./config
./config/webpack.prod.js
./config/webpack.dev.js
./config/paths.js
./config/webpack.common.js
./.eslintrc
./package-lock.json
./LICENSE
```

## Evaluated files with webpack config #1

```
src/pages/home/index.js
```

## Evaluated files with webpack config #2

```
src/index.html
src/index.js
src/styles/index.scss
src/pages/home/index.js
src/route/nourl/index.js
```

## My goal

Develop a webpack loader just for all js files inside of a specific folder. In my case folder is src/pages and expected files :

```
./src/pages/map/index.js
./src/pages/home/index.js
```

## Questions

- How configure loader for evaluate all files in a specific folder?
- Why my webpack configuration #1 picks one file?
- Why my webpack configuration #2 picks random files instead all files due to this regex: /.*$/?

## Environment

- linux
- nodejs 8
- "webpack": "^4.39.3"

Answer (score 0):

Webpack loader will be execute the loaders just if those have been imported.

So in case of your loader is not executing for your js file, you must import this file in your application:

```
const Home = require('../../MyJsModule')
```

Webpack will **detect** this require and you loader will detect it!